# ref input value in Enzyme test expected to be empty string but returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

**Edit** Here is a Code Sandbox of this: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-bt34v

Unfortunately, I cannot get the Enzyme configuration to work in the Sandbox, but the essential code for this issue is all there, and clicking the button will print the `typeof` value for the input box.

---

I'm trying to write a test that tests how an `input` element's value should change after a `Button` is clicked.

Here is the function that's called when the Button component is clicked, `stopTimer`, which calls a useReducer `dispatch()` to update the useReducer's state `store`, and below that is what the button looks like.

```
  const stopTimer = (): void => {
    dispatch({
      payload: state.totalSeconds,
      type: 'stop',
    });

...

   <Button handleClick={ stopTimer } />
```

In another file, this is what the useReducer looks like, and below that is a `useEffect` that is called when the `store` changes. It updates the value of a `ref` to an empty `''` string whenever the `store` is updated.

```
  const [store, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, dashboardStore);

...

  useEffect((): void => {
    ref.current!.value = '';
  }, [store]);

...

  <input ref={ref} type='text'></input>
```

To test this with Enzyme, I mount the parent component `<Dashboard />` and I give the input an initial value of `'hello'`. I then invoke the Button's `handleClick` prop, which should call the useReducer's `dispatch` function, updating the `store`, then causing `useEffect` to fire, which should set the input's value to an empty string.

I'm expecting the input's value to be an empty string after this, but it ends up being `undefined`.

I'm also using Enzyme's `debug()` to try to verify what the DOM looks like at various times. When I do not invoke the Button's `handleClick`, or if I do not call `wrapper.update()`, the input's value is `'hello'` as expected, but `debug()` shows the input not having a `value` prop after `update()` is called.

```js
    it('should contain an empty string when the stop button is clicked', () => {
      const wrapper = mount(<Dashboard />);
      wrapper.find('input').props().value = 'hello';
      act(() => wrapper.find(Button).props().handleClick());

      wrapper.update();
      console.log(wrapper.find('input').debug());
      expect(wrapper.find('input').props().value).toBe('');
    });
```

Comment: did you verify this works as expected in the browser before writing the test?

Comment: Yes, it works as expected in the browser. Inside the `useEffect`, right after I set the input value to an empty string I log `console.log(typeof ref?.current?.value);`, which logs `string`.

Comment: Seeing if I can make a Code Sandbox of this..